# Detect if the mouse is not over an element in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to be able to detect if the mouse is over a certain div. So I do this

```
if ($('#mydv').is(':hover')) {
    //doSometing
});
```

how do I detect if the mouse in not over the div? Also I read that this might not work if the element is an iframe. Is there a way to make this work in an iframe as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and flags like

```
var isOver = false;
$('#mydv').hover(function() {
    isOver = true;
}, function() {
    isOver = false;
});
. 
.
.
//elsewhere in your code you can use isOver to know whether the cursor is over or not
```

Comment: you can access `isOver` in the callback for `setTimeout`, however, note `setTimeout` itself returns an id

Comment: @Becky, no problem. Let me know if you still need more help regarding this question :)

Comment: I'm having a problem setting the `isOver` inside the `setInterval()`.  `function chk() {
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if (isOver == true) {
      //do stuff
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 3000);
}` the `clearInterval()` does not work even when the mouse is over?